# Migrating data from older mysql installation to new one in mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I had mysql version 5.7.12 in my macOS High Siera full of database files stored in /usr/local/mysql-5.7.12-osx10.11-x86_64/data directory. Then I updated mysql to 5.7.23 and a new directory is created as /usr/local/mysql-5.7.23-macos10.13-x86_64/data in which the upgraded mysql expects the database files to reside. Can I simply copy the database files from the older directory to this one and restore my data? I don't want to export the databases and import them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

- Stopped mysql
- Copied all the database file/directories and a file called **ibdata1** (the tablespace for InnoDB) from the older data directory (/usr/local/mysql-5.7.12-osx10.11-x86_64/data) to the new one (/usr/local/mysql-5.7.23-macos10.13-x86_64/data).
- Granted necessary privileges to database users.
- Started mysql and everything comes back.

[P.S. I need to do this because the database files are multiple tens of GB in size and I don't have the necessary disk space to backup and restore.]